# How can I show column data in PhpMyAdmin on insert?

Tags: mysql, database

When I insert a record with a foreign key relationship, how can I change the drop-down to show another foreign table column? By default, it shows the foreign table's primary key (an int) that isn't very descriptive. Can I force it to display another field (like a varchar field with description) from the same foreign table?

For example, if there are foreign table GenderID's of 1=Male and 2=Female, and the foreign key is Person.GenderID, how can I force the dropdown to read "Male" or "Female" instead of "1" or "2"?

example tables:

```
Gender
GenderID  GenderDescription
1         Male
2         Female

Person
PersonID  GenderID
1         2
2         2
3         1
```

MySQL v5.1.41
tables InnoDB

Comment: Similar to: http://serverfault.com/questions/180847/phpmyadmin-can-i-view-actual-field-values-instead-of-the-foreign-keys/180878#180878 (I haven't seen any indication that phpMyAdmin will support this behavior, but I'd be happy to be wrong)

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I found, in PMA documentation, the ability to produce a tooltip when browsing data, but you understood that wasn't what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In the referenced table (Gender) you can go to "Relation view" and under the table there is a select box "Choose field to display", in which you choose column that will be displayed next to GenderId value in the referencing table (Person). 
[phpymadminWiki](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_6.21)